# How do i get the HTML element in the same row as a XPATH Contains?

Tags: html, dom, selenium, xpath

I am using Selenium with Python. I have a table. I found the row which has the text 'Honorable' in it by using this Xpath :-

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(., 'Honorable')]")
```

Now I need to click the Edit button which has the below HTML (taken from Chrome's Inspector Tools)

```
<a id="prefixmasterListForm:prefixMasterTable:0:editLink
```

The full HTML is:

```
<tr class="rich-table-row rich-table-firstrow ">
    <td class="rich-table-cell " id="prefixmasterListForm:prefixMasterTable:0:j_id347" width="auto">
        Honorable
    </td>
    <td class="rich-table-cell alignCenter" id="prefixmasterListForm:prefixMasterTable:0:j_id350" width="auto">
        <img id="prefixmasterListForm:prefixMasterTable:0:activeic" src="images/yes.gif" alt="active">
    </td>
    <td class="rich-table-cell " id="prefixmasterListForm:prefixMasterTable:0:j_id352" width="auto">
        General Prefix
    </td>
    <td class="rich-table-cell " id="prefixmasterListForm:prefixMasterTable:0:j_id360" width="auto">
        MALE
    </td>
    <td class="rich-table-cell " id="prefixmasterListForm:prefixMasterTable:0:column6" width="auto">
        <a id="prefixmasterListForm:prefixMasterTable:0:editLink" href="#" onclick="if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function'){jsfcljs(document.forms['prefixmasterListForm'],'prefixmasterListForm:prefixMasterTable:0:editLink,prefixmasterListForm:prefixMasterTable:0:editLink,prefixMasterId,15661602','');}return false">
            <img src="images/iconedit.gif" alt="Edit" class="image">
        </a>
        <a id="prefixmasterListForm:prefixMasterTable:0:deleteLink" href="#" onclick="if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function'){jsfcljs(document.forms['prefixmasterListForm'],'prefixmasterListForm:prefixMasterTable:0:deleteLink,prefixmasterListForm:prefixMasterTable:0:deleteLink,prefixMasterId,15661602,prefixMasterName,Honorable','');}return false">
            <img src="images/icondelete.gif" alt="delete" class="image">
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

How do i get hold of that Edit link element using XPath?

Based on Arran's help i also checked that the column next to 'Honorable' has an image with alt=inactive like this

```
"//td[normalize-space(text())='Honorable']/following-sibling::td[img[@alt='inactive']]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//td[normalize-space(text())='Honorable']/following-sibling::td//a[.//img[@alt='Edit']]
```

The `td` that has it's `text` **equal** to 'Honorable', then get the `td` following it, that has an `a` inside it, which has an `image` within it that has it's `alt` attribute set to 'Edit'

Comment: Now what if i want to check the image in the next TD to 'Honorable' which has an alt of 'Inactive' ? //td[normalize-space(text())='Honorable']/following-sibling::td//img[@alt='inactive']"

Comment: @Chakra Correct. If it doesn't work correctly, let us know by creating a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Try: `//a[@id='prefixmasterListForm:prefixMasterTable:0:editLink']`

P.S.If you want to verify or do some easy job with xpath, you can install **FF + FireBug + FirePath**

Answer (score 1):

Easy: `//tr[td[contains(., 'Honorable')]]/td/a[contains(@id, ':editLink)]` - literally, the `A` contained in the `TD` contained in the `TR` that also contains a `TD` that contains the string "Honorable".